# simulate click in IE 9 javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling, click

I found this code snippet here, works perfectly but not for IE.

```
var testTwo = document.getElementById('testOne')

function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}

function testInt(){
eventFire(testTwo, "click");
};
setInterval(testInt, 3000);
```

can anyone tell me how to get it work in IE?

thank you

Comment: If you can use it, [jQuery](http://jquery.com) will take care of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function eventFire(el, etype) {
    var event;
    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(etype, true, true);
    } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = etype;
    }

    event.eventName = etype;

    if (el.dispatchEvent) {
        el.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        el.fireEvent("on" + etype, event);
    }
}}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fc5Yk/2/)

Logic taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `fireEvent` to trigger the event.  [Here is the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about it.